# Getting the amount of time that the service is running

Tags: java, android, service

Is it possible to get the amount of time that a service is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "running" you mean "exists in memory":

Step #1: Store the start time in a data member of the service in `onCreate()`.

Step #2: When you need it, subtract the start time from the current time to determine how long the service has been in memory.

Comment: I knew that it possible by using a Timer class for example but I've seen that on my android phone applcation manager I can see how much time my app service is running so I thought that maybe I can use the same source as they do in order to see how long the service is running, so I guess it's not possible right?

Comment: @ImriPersiado: I do not know of a way to get that information from the OS, sorry.